# Sitecore query filter issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am new to Sitecore and have come across a situation for which I haven't been able to find any documentation.

I have two blogs, `Blog A` and `Blog B`. Each Blog has various `Categories`.

Now, I am trying to create a template, where the user can select a Blog and then select Categories. For Bog Selection, I have used a ***Droptree*** and for Categories Selection, I have used a ***Multilist***. I can fetch all the Categories using the following query :

```
query:../../..//*[@@templatename= 'Category']
```

But, this fetches all the categories belonging to both the Blogs. What I want to do is - when the user has selected the Blog in the DropTree, I want to populate the Multilist only with the categories belonging to that particular blog.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you not create 2 templates, BlogA and BlogB and then the filtering will be very easy since you can set it in the standard values for each? Use the Insert Options to give the user quick option to create a blog entry for each type rather than a droptree field.

Comment: The blog Component is used in various places and not just 2. I gave this just as an example. So, not ideal to create several templates. Insert Options are fine for inserting a new entry. Here I want to filter the items displayed in the MultiList based on the DropTree selection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Sitecore Query supports what you're after (basically using a field value from another item as a variable in a query, if I understand correctly).

There's a guide to the whole of query on SDN: http://sdn.sitecore.net/reference/using%20sitecore%20query/sitecore%20query%20syntax.aspx

I think I'd look at creating a custom field type that inherited from multilist and overriding the logic that pulls items based on the data source - then you can filter it programmatically however you want. There are various blog posts available on that subject, such as http://gettingtoknowsitecore.blogspot.com/2010/03/custom-fields-part-1.html

You could also consider putting categories as subitems under each blog to drastically simplify the whole thing - then you could simply use a relative query or an ancestor-or-self query without anything custom.

Comment: Thanks, Kam. Links are very useful. Actually, Categories are under Blog. So, different categories for each Blog. But I still couldn't figure out if there was a way to filter Categories based on the Blog the user has selected in the DropTree. Does that make sense?